# How to count number of variables in a dictionary

Tags: python, csv, count

This is my current code to append different time to the same name id in a dict.

> ```
> for name, date, time ,price in reader(f):
>           group_dict[name].append([time])
> ```

my question is how do i count the number of 'time' i have in each key in the dict ?

An example of output is

```
 {(name1): [time1, time2, time3]}
```

and i am trying a way to include the count '3' inside

Comment: Your question is not really clear. Do you want the sum of all counts? Or each of the counts individually? Do you just want to display these counts, or store them somewhere (like the original dict)?

Comment: i wish to display the count as part of the dictionary key so example a list with 3 'time' element inside will contain 3 in one of its dict key

Answer (score 2):

```
for key, value in yourDict.iteritems():
    print len(value)
```

if you want include to your structure try:

```
for key, value in yourDict.iteritems():
    yourDict[key] = (value, len(value))
```

Code for python2 for python 3 use items() instead of iteritems()

Comment: i am getting a bit confused here. in my case what should the 'key' be?

Comment: Have you tested your second example? it seems to raise an error.

Comment: You need to change `for key, value in yourDict:` to `for key, value in yourDict.items():` in both cases (or `yourDict.iteritems()` in Python 2).

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you want by reassigning your key's value to include the length of its value:

```
for key, value in yourDict.items(): # Change to .iteritems() if using Python 2.x
    yourDict[key] = value + [len(value)]
```

Or, you could do this using dictionary comprehension:

```
yourDict = {key:value+[len(value)] for key, value in yourDict.items()} # Python 3.x
yourDict = {key:value+[len(value)] for key, value in yourDict.iteritems()} # Python 2.x
```